# How is journalctl able to add the line with the "-- Reboot --" log message?

Tags: logs, systemd-journald, journalctl

I've noticed, on machines where the journalctl logs are saved on disk, that on a reboot, I get a line between the message before and after the reboot happened like so:

```
blah
blah
blah
-- Reboot --
blah
blah
blah
```

How does journalctl know to add that line at that location?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`journalctl` keeps track of the `boot_id` attached to logs, and when that changes, [indicates that the system rebooted](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/f127fed75d3bae3a1eb0be6feea334bb8d1c3a43/src/journal/journalctl.c#L2665).

The `boot_id` is [generated by the kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/kernel.html#random), and can be retrieved from `/proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id`.